# R how to speed up pattern matching using vectors

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a column in one dataframe with city and state names in it:

`ac <- c("san francisco ca", "pittsburgh pa", "philadelphia pa", "washington dc", "new york ny", "aliquippa pa", "gainesville fl", "manhattan ks")`

`ac <- as.data.frame(ac)`

I would like to search for the values in `ac$ac` in another data frame column, `d$description` and return the value of column `id` if there is a match.

```
dput(df)
structure(list(month = c(202110L, 201910L, 202005L, 201703L, 
201208L, 201502L), id = c(100559687L, 100558763L, 100558934L, 
100558946L, 100543422L, 100547618L), description = c("residential local telephone service local with more san francisco ca flat rate with eas package plan includes voicemail call forwarding call waiting caller id call restriction three way calling id block speed dialing call return call screening modem rental voip transmission telephone access line 34 95 modem rental 7 00 total 41 95", 
"digital video programming service multilatino ultra bensalem pa service includes digital economy multilatino digital preferred tier and certain additonal digital channels coaxial cable transmission", 
"residential all distance telephone service  unlimited  voice only harrisburg pa flat rate with eas only features call waiting caller id caller id with call waiting call screening call forwarding call forwarding selective call return 69 3 way calling anonymous call rejection repeat dialing speed dial caller id blocking coaxial cable transmission", 
"residential all distance telephone service  unlimited voice only pittsburgh pa flat rate with eas only features call waiting caller id caller id with call waiting call screening call forwarding call forwarding selective call return 69 3 way calling anonymous call rejection repeat dialing speed dial caller id blocking", 
"local spot advertising 30 second advertisement austin tx weekday 6 am 6 pm other audience demographic w18 49 number of rating points for daypart 0 29 average cpp 125", 
"residential public switched toll interstate manhattan ks ks plan area residence switched toll base period average revenue per minute 0 18 minute online"
)), row.names = c(1L, 1245L, 3800L, 10538L, 20362L, 50000L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried to do this via accessing the row indexes of the matches via the following methods:

1. `which(ac$ac %in% df$description)`--this returns `integer(0)`.
2. `grep(ac$ac, df$description, value = FALSE)`--this returns the first index, 1.  But this isn't vectorized.
3. `str_detect(string = ac$ac, pattern = df$description)` -- but this returns all `FALSE` which is incorrect.

My question:  how do I search for `ac$ac` in `df$description` and return the corresponding value of `df$id` in the event of a match?  Note that the vectors are not of the same length.  **I am looking for ALL matches, not just the first**.  I would prefer something simple and fast, because the actual datasets that I will be using have over 100k rows each but any suggestions or ideas are welcome.  Thanks.

**Edit.  Due to Andre's initial answer below, the name of the question was changed to account for the change in the scope of the question.**

**Edit (12/7): bounty added to generate additional interest and a fast, efficient scalable solution.**

**Edit (12/8):  Clarification--I would like to be able to add the `id` variable from `df` to the `ac` dataframe, as in `ac$id`.**

Comment: The question is changed after the answer is given. The name of the variable was replaced. Should you change a significant part of your question you'd better append your question with a new block otherwise the people voluntary answering your questions will seem to loose their time as their answers become senseless.

Comment: @asd-tm fair point.  I should have updated my question.  I have now edited. Hopefully this is sufficient.

Comment: my note was devoted to my answer concerning the name of variables

Comment: Did I understood it correctly: in one description string there is only maximally 1 city mentioned?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim not necessarily

Comment: I ask because otherwise one could capture/collect the result in a vector instead of a list.

Comment: I would like to add the result to the original dataframe, `ac`

Comment: @javlenti I updated my answer. Hope it's what you expected now.

Comment: Hey @jvalenti. I added one more update to my answer. Hope you finally find the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest solutions are usually the fastest!
Here is my suggestion:

```
str = paste0(ac, collapse="|")
df$id[grep(str, df$description)]
```

But you can also this way

```
df$id[as.logical(rowSums(!is.na(sapply(ac, function(x) stringr::str_match(df$description, x)))))]
```

Or this way

```
df$id[grepl(str, df$description, perl=T)]
```

However, it has to be compared. By the way, I added suggestions from @Andre Wildberg and @Martina C. Arnolda.
Below is the Benchmark.

```
str = paste0(ac, collapse="|")
fFiolka1 = function() df$id[grep(str, df$description)]
fFiolka2 = function() df$id[as.logical(rowSums(!is.na(sapply(ac, function(x) stringr::str_match(df$description, x)))))]
fFiolka3 = function() df$id[grepl(str, df$description, perl=T)]

fWildberg1 = function() df$id[unlist(sapply(ac, function(x) grep(x, df$description)))]
fWildberg2 = function() df$id[as.logical(rowSums(sapply(ac, function(x) stri_detect_regex(df$description, x))))]

fArnolda1 = function() df[grep(str, df$description), ]["id"]
fArnolda2 = function() df[stringi::stri_detect_regex(df$description, str), ]["id"]
fArnolda3 = function() df %>% filter(description %>% str_detect(str)) %>% select(id)

library(microbenchmark)
ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(
  fFiolka1(), fFiolka2(), fFiolka3(),
  fWildberg1(), fWildberg2(),
  fArnolda1(), fArnolda2(), fArnolda3(),
  times=100))
```

[image]

Note, for the sake of simplicity I left ac as a vector !.

```
ac <- c("san francisco ca", "pittsburgh pa", "philadelphia pa", "washington dc", "new york ny", "aliquippa pa", "gainesville fl", "manhattan ks")
```

### Special update for @jvalenti

OKAY. Now I understand better what you want to achieve. However, in order to fully show the best solution, I have slightly modified your data. Here they are

```
library(tidyverse)

ac <- c("san francisco ca", "pittsburgh pa", "philadelphia pa", "washington dc", "new york ny", "aliquippa pa", "gainesville fl", "manhattan ks")
ac = tibble(ac = ac)

df = structure(list(
  month = c(202110L, 201910L, 202005L, 201703L, 201208L, 201502L), 
  id = c(100559687L, 100558763L, 100558934L, 100558946L, 100543422L, 100547618L), 
  description = c(
    "residential local telephone pittsburgh pa local with more san francisco ca flat rate with eas philadelphia pa plan includes voicemail call forwarding call waiting caller id call restriction three way calling id block speed dialing call return call screening modem rental voip transmission telephone access line 34 95 modem rental 7 00 total 41 95",
    "digital video san francisco ca pittsburgh pa  multilatino ultra bensalem pa service includes digital economy multilatino digital preferred tier and certain additonal digital channels coaxial cable transmission",
    "residential all distance telephone pittsburgh pa unlimited voice only harrisburg pa flat rate with eas only features call waiting caller id caller id with call waiting call screening call forwarding call forwarding selective call return 69 3 way calling anonymous call rejection repeat dialing speed dial caller id blocking coaxial cable transmission",
    "residential all distance telephone pittsburgh pa unlimited voice philadelphia pa san francisco ca pa flat rate with eas only features call waiting caller id caller id with call waiting call screening call forwarding call forwarding selective call return 69 3 way calling anonymous call rejection repeat dialing speed dial caller id blocking",
    "local spot advertising 30 second advertisement austin tx weekday 6 am 6 pm other audience demographic w18 49 number of rating points for daypart 0 29 average cpp 125",
    "residential public switched toll pittsburgh pa manhattan ks ks plan area residence switched toll base san philadelphia pa ca average revenue per minute 0 18 minute online"
  )), row.names = c(1L, 1245L, 3800L, 10538L, 20362L, 50000L), class = "data.frame")
```

Below you will find four different solutions. One based on the `for` loop, two solutions based on the functions from the `dplyr` package, and yet a function from the `collapse` package.

```
fSolition1 = function(){
  id = vector("list", nrow(ac))
  for(i in seq_along(ac$ac)){
    id[[i]] = df$id[grep(ac$ac[i], df$description)]
  }
  ac %>% mutate(id = id) %>% unnest(id)
}
fSolition1()

fSolition2 = function(){
  ac %>% group_by(ac) %>% 
  mutate(id = list(df$id[grep(ac, df$description)])) %>% 
  unnest(id)
}
fSolition2()

fSolition3 = function(){
  ac %>% rowwise(ac) %>% 
  mutate(id = list(df$id[grep(ac, df$description)])) %>% 
  unnest(id)
}
fSolition3()

fSolition4 = function(){
ac %>%  
  collapse::ftransform(id = lapply(ac, function(x) df$id[grep(x, df$description)])) %>% 
  unnest(id)
}
fSolition4()
```

Note that for the given data, all functions that return the following table as a result

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   ac                      id
   <chr>                <int>
 1 san francisco ca 100559687
 2 san francisco ca 100558763
 3 san francisco ca 100558946
 4 pittsburgh pa    100559687
 5 pittsburgh pa    100558763
 6 pittsburgh pa    100558934
 7 pittsburgh pa    100558946
 8 pittsburgh pa    100547618
 9 philadelphia pa  100559687
10 philadelphia pa  100558946
11 philadelphia pa  100547618
12 manhattan ks     100547618
```

It's time for a benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(
  fSolition1(), fSolition2(), fSolition3(), fSolition4(), times=100))
```

[image]

It is perhaps no surprise to anyone that the `collapse` based solution is the fastest. However, second place may be a big surprise. The good old solution based on the **`for` function is in second place!!** Anyone else want to say that **`for` is slow?**

### Special update for @Gwang-Jin Kim

The actions on vectors did not change much. Look below.

```
df_ac = ac$ac
df_decription = df$description
df_id = df$id
fSolition5 = function(){
  id = vector("list", length = length(df_ac))
  for(i in seq_along(df_ac)){
    id[[i]] = df_id[grep(df_ac[i], df_decription)]
  }
  ac %>% mutate(id = id) %>% unnest(id)
}
fSolition5()

library(microbenchmark)
ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(
  fSolition1(), fSolition2(), fSolition3(), fSolition4(), fSolition5(), times=100))
```

[image]

But the combination of `for` and `ftransform` can be surprising !!!

```
fSolition6 = function(){
  id = vector("list", nrow(ac))
  for(i in seq_along(ac$ac)){
    id[[i]] = df$id[grep(ac$ac[i], df$description)]
  }
  ac %>% collapse::ftransform(id = id) %>% unnest(id)
}
fSolition6()

library(microbenchmark)
ggplot2::autoplot(microbenchmark(
  fSolition1(), fSolition2(), fSolition3(), fSolition4(), fSolition5(), fSolition6(), times=100))
```

[image]

### Last update for @jvalenti

Dear jvaleniti, in your question you wrote *I have a column in one dataframe with city and state names* and then *I will be using have over 100k rows*. My conclusion is that it is very likely that a given city will appear several times in your variable `description`.

However, in the comment you wrote *I don't want to change the number of rows in ac*
So what kind of results do you expect? Let's see what can be done with it.

Solution 1 - we return all `id` as a list of vectors

```
ac %>% collapse::ftransform(id = map(ac, ~df$id[grep(.x, df$description)])) 
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
# ac               id       
# * <chr>            <list>   
#   1 san francisco ca <int [3]>
#   2 pittsburgh pa    <int [5]>
#   3 philadelphia pa  <int [3]>
#   4 washington dc    <int [0]>
#   5 new york ny      <int [0]>
#   6 aliquippa pa     <int [0]>
#   7 gainesville fl   <int [0]>
#   8 manhattan ks     <int [1]>
```

Solution 2 - we only return the first `id`

```
ac %>% collapse::ftransform(id = map_int(ac, ~df$id[grep(.x, df$description)][1])) 
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
# ac                      id
# * <chr>                <int>
# 1 san francisco ca 100559687
# 2 pittsburgh pa    100559687
# 3 philadelphia pa  100559687
# 4 washington dc           NA
# 5 new york ny             NA
# 6 aliquippa pa            NA
# 7 gainesville fl          NA
# 8 manhattan ks     100547618
```

Solution 3 - we only return the last `id`

```
ac %>%
  collapse::ftransform(id = map_int(ac, function(x) {
    idx = grep(x, df$description)
    ifelse(length(idx)>0, df$id[idx[length(idx)]], NA)})) 
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
# ac                      id
# * <chr>                <int>
# 1 san francisco ca 100558946
# 2 pittsburgh pa    100547618
# 3 philadelphia pa  100547618
# 4 washington dc           NA
# 5 new york ny             NA
# 6 aliquippa pa            NA
# 7 gainesville fl          NA
# 8 manhattan ks     100547618
```

Solution 4 - or maybe you would like to choose any `id` from all possible

```
ac %>%
  collapse::ftransform(id = map_int(ac, function(x) {
    idx = grep(x, df$description)
    ifelse(length(idx)==0, NA, ifelse(length(idx)==1, df$id[idx], df$id[sample(idx, 1)]))})) 
# # A tibble: 8 x 2
# ac                      id
# * <chr>                <int>
# 1 san francisco ca 100558763
# 2 pittsburgh pa    100559687
# 3 philadelphia pa  100547618
# 4 washington dc           NA
# 5 new york ny             NA
# 6 aliquippa pa            NA
# 7 gainesville fl          NA
# 8 manhattan ks     100547618
```

Solution 5 - if you accidentally wanted to see all the id's and wanted to keep the number of `ac` lines at the same time

```
ac %>%
  collapse::ftransform(id = map(ac, function(x) {
    idx = grep(x, df$description)
    if(length(idx)==0) tibble(id = NA, idn = "id1") else tibble(
      id = df$id[idx],
      idn = paste0("id",1:length(id)))})) %>% 
  unnest(id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(ac, names_from = idn, values_from = id)
# # A tibble: 8 x 6
# ac                     id1       id2       id3       id4       id5
# <chr>                <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>
# 1 san francisco ca 100559687 100558763 100558946        NA        NA
# 2 pittsburgh pa    100559687 100558763 100558934 100558946 100547618
# 3 philadelphia pa  100559687 100558946 100547618        NA        NA
# 4 washington dc           NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# 5 new york ny             NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# 6 aliquippa pa            NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# 7 gainesville fl          NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
# 8 manhattan ks     100547618        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Unfortunately, the description provided by you does not indicate which of the above five solutions is an acceptable solution for you. You will have to decide for yourself.

Comment: I need to add the `id` column to my original `ac` dataframe.  Since the two have different lengths how would this work?

Comment: what if `uniqe(ac$ac)` were used?

Comment: leaving it as a vector or working on data frames will make a difference in speed, definitely.

Comment: this is great, but it doesn't return the original dataframe, only the matches.  is it possible to return the original dataframe, `ac` with the orignal number of rows, and the `id` var appended with blanks or `NA` in the rows without matches? I don't want to change the number of rows in `ac`.  Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Can you bother my curiosity and tell me which version of the solution you finally adopted?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `sapply` with `grep`.

```
df$id[ unlist( sapply( ac$ac, function(x) grep(x, df$description ) ) ) ]
[1] 100559687 100558946 100547618
```

EDIT, try `stri_detect_regex` from `stringi`. Should be 2-5 times faster.

```
library(stringi)

df$id[ as.logical( rowSums( sapply( ac$ac, function(x) 
  stri_detect_regex( df$description, x ) ) ) ) ]
[1] 100559687 100558946 100547618
```

**Microbenchmark** on an extended data set with **1.728M** rows:
Memory should not be a problem unless you are using a system with less than 4Gb RAM total.

```
nrow(df)
[1] 1728000

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark( 
  "grep1" = { res <- sapply(ac$ac, function(x) df$id[grep(x, df$description)]) },
  "grep2" = { res <- df$id[ unlist( sapply( ac$ac, function(x) grep(x, df$description ) ) ) ] },
  "stringi" = { res <- df$id[ as.logical( rowSums( sapply( ac$ac, function(x) stri_detect_regex( df$description, x ) ) ) ) ] }, times=10 )

Unit: seconds
   expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval cld
  grep1 96.90757 97.98706 100.13299 99.05837 101.99050 107.04312    10   b
  grep2 97.51382 97.66425 100.00610 99.20753 101.17921 106.86661    10   b
stringi 46.15548 46.65894  48.68073 47.29635  50.15713  53.50351    10  a
```

> Memory footprint during microbenchmark:
> Path: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/bin/exec/R
> Physical footprint:        638.3M
> Physical footprint (peak): 1.8G

Comment: this appears to work but is very slow

Comment: @asd-tm Thanks for the note! I was in the process of editing and then saw the changes. So all updated in the answer.

Comment: @Andre sorry I posted the comment to your answer by mistake instead of placing it under the question!

Comment: @asd-tm No worries, kinda helpful for recent answers to know if their code still works. And by the wording I knew you meant the OP :)

Comment: I like this solution because it's simple and readable but it doesn't seem to work for scale.  When I tried I got an error from R: `cannot allocate vector of size 2 GB`

Comment: I think the problem is that I've been trying to add the `id` variable to my `ac` `dataframe`?  Then I start getting errors with the toy data.

Comment: @jvalenti Yes, that would increase the memory footprint. I also would not alter the object used in regex comparisons while looping.

Comment: is there a way to add the `id` var to the `ac` dataframe that's memory neutral?

Comment: @jvalenti Most low impact would probably be to generate a vector and add it after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is an option?

```
ac$id <- sapply(ac$ac, function(x) d$id[grep(x, d$description)])
#                 ac        id
# 1 san francisco ca 100559687
# 2    pittsburgh pa 100558946
# 3  philadelphia pa          
# 4    washington dc          
# 5      new york ny          
# 6     aliquippa pa          
# 7   gainesville fl          
# 8     manhattan ks 100547618
```

Comment: it would be a bit faster when applying `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 2):

Checking using a regular expression and non-expensive functions should be fast:

First, we generate the pattern to be checked: `ac_regex <- paste(ac$ac, collapse =  "|")`.

There are several ways to detect matches in `description` and subset. Here are three:

```r
# 1 grep()
df[grep(ac_regex, df$description), ]["id"],
# 2 stringi::stri_detect_*()
df[stri_detect_regex(df$description, ac_regex), ]["id"],
# 3 stringr::str_detect() + tidy subsetting
df %>% filter(description %>% str_detect(ac_regex)) %>% select(id),
```

All three return the desired subset of `df`:

```
         id
1 100559687
2 100558946
3 100547618
```

(You need the packages `tidyverse` and `stringi` for options 2 and 3.)

Let's benchmark (using package `bench`):

```r
bench::mark(
  base_grep = df[grep(ac_regex, df$description), ]["id"],
  base_stringi = df[stringi::stri_detect_regex(df$description, ac_regex), ]["id"],
  tidy = df %>% filter(description %>% str_detect(ac_regex)) %>% select(id),
  check = F
)
```

```
  expression     median 
  <bch:expr>   <bch:tm>   
1 base_grep    146.61µs      
2 base_stringi  119.6µs     
3 tidy           1.99ms
```

I'd go with `stringi`!

Comment: for some reason this gives an `invalid regular expression` error when used on the whole dataframe.  In addition there's a warning:  `In grep(ac_regex, df$description): TRE pattern compilation error 'Out of memory'`.  I don't see how I'm out of memory when I have plenty of RAM.

Comment: This is because `paste0()` needs `ac` to be a vector. I've forgotten to include this in my answer. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regex_inner_join` from package `fuzzyjoin`

```
> library(fuzzyjoin)

> regex_inner_join(df, ac, by = c(description = "ac"))
   month        id
1 202110 100559687
2 201703 100558946
3 201502 100547618

                                                              description
1 residential local telephone service local with more san francisco ca flat rate with eas package plan includes voicemail call forwarding call waiting caller id call restriction three way calling id block speed dialing call return call screening modem rental voip transmission telephone access line 34 95 modem rental 7 00 total 41 95
2               residential all distance telephone service  unlimited voice only pittsburgh pa flat rate with eas only features call waiting caller id caller id with call waiting call screening call forwarding call forwarding selective call return 69 3 way calling anonymous call rejection repeat dialing speed dial caller id blocking
3                                                                                                                                                                                      residential public switched toll interstate manhattan ks ks plan area residence switched toll base period average revenue per minute 0 18 minute online
                ac
1 san francisco ca
2    pittsburgh pa
3     manhattan ks
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is no `c$c` assignment in the provided code. All the data is assigned to a variable called `c`. This variable does not have any `c` members (`c$c`) you are trying to work with.

Second it is a very bad practice to assign any data to variables called as the basic functions of R `c <- c(...)`.